# How to split two array and pass to ajax using Jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, codeigniter

I am getting an error while inserting into my database.

Its showing column ARRAY. How to fix it? Instead of that I want to pass all dates (showing in the screenshot only dates in the date column)

I want to know in code where I did mistake. Why the array is coming like this?

PHP MODAL

```
$data_jobschedule = array(
            'jobschedule_id' => $jobschedule_id,
            'Activity_area_id' => $Activity_area_id,
            'Contract_id' => $this->input->post('getcontract_id'),
            'job_freq_id' => $this->input->post('getcontractbranch_freq'),
            'job_schedule_dates' => $this->input->post('getschedule'),
            //'job_schedule_frequency' => $this->input->post('getjob_schedule_frequency'),
            'created_at' =>$created_Dt
        );

 $insert_id = 0;
        if ($this->db->insert("activity_area", $data)) { //AM INSERTING ANOTHER RECORD ALSO TO DIFFERENT TABLE
            $this->db->insert('job_schedule', $data_jobschedule); //HERE IS THE TABLE I NEED TO ADD DATES AND FREQUENCY
            $insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();

        }
```

Comment: you are inserting an array into a column

Comment: so basically you want to store the `job_schedule_dates` array value as a column  to your `job_schedule` table? but you mentioned **Database table looks** with Date and  treatment, what is the meaning of it?

Comment: in database two columns are there Date and Frequency along with other columns like jobschedule_id, Activity_area_id, Contract_id, job_freq_id etc. so you need something like jobschedule_id, Activity_area_id, Contract_id, job_freq_id, **Date, treatment**, created_at ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so your post data is an array, you need looping through it.
on your php model, try change this

```
$data_jobschedule = array(
    'jobschedule_id' => $jobschedule_id,
    'Activity_area_id' => $Activity_area_id,
    'Contract_id' => $this->input->post('getcontract_id'),
    'job_freq_id' => $this->input->post('getcontractbranch_freq'),
    'job_schedule_dates' => $this->input->post('getschedule'),
    //'job_schedule_frequency' => $this->input->post('getjob_schedule_frequency'),
    'created_at' =>$created_Dt
);

$insert_id = 0;
if ($this->db->insert("activity_area", $data)) { //AM INSERTING ANOTHER RECORD ALSO TO DIFFERENT TABLE
    $this->db->insert('job_schedule', $data_jobschedule); //HERE IS THE TABLE I NEED TO ADD DATES AND FREQUENCY
    $insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

to

```
$insert_id = 0;
if ($this->db->insert("activity_area", $data)) { //AM INSERTING ANOTHER RECORD ALSO TO DIFFERENT TABLE
    if (is_array($this->input->post('getschedule'))) {
        foreach($this->input->post('getschedule') as $value) {
            $this->db->insert('job_schedule', array(
                'jobschedule_id' => $jobschedule_id,
                'Activity_area_id' => $Activity_area_id,
                'Contract_id' => $this->input->post('getcontract_id'),
                'job_freq_id' => $this->input->post('getcontractbranch_freq'),
                'job_schedule_dates' => $value[0], //assume array form like your screenshot
                'job_schedule_frequency' => $value[1],
                'created_at' =>$created_Dt
            ));
        }

        $insert_id = $this->db->insert_id(); 
    }
}
```